# Writing a 'for loop' for random no which is not zero(0) but still I'm getting zero(0)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to dart, and I'm writing the following for loop for random num which is not a zero, but it still returns zero to me:

```dart
  int Num = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i != 0 && i <= 6; i++) {
    final _random = Random();
    Num = _random.nextInt(i);
  }
  print('Randon num is $Num');
```

Comment: Random function(n) in dart returns a number from [0,n-1]. That's why you're getting 0. :)

Comment: What's the `i != 0` check meant to be checking for you? You initialize `i` to `1` and increment it. If you're trying to break your loop when you've got a non-zero random number, you're checking the wrong variable and have the wrong termination condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place for problems like this is the dart api.
This [link](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-math/Random-class.html) provides you with everything you need.

Here it says the following:

> nextInt(int max) → int Generates a non-negative random integer
> uniformly distributed in the range from 0, inclusive, to max,
> exclusive. [...]
> Also i represents the max value the nextInt() method will produce.

**To generate a single random number:**

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  int maxNb = 10; 
  
  generateRandomNumber(int maxNb) {
    final int number = Random().nextInt(maxNb) + 1; 
    return number;
  }
  
  int result = generateRandomNumber(maxNb);
  print(result);
}
```

**To generate multiple random numbers:**

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  int maxNb = 10;
  int amount = 6;
  List randomNumbers = [];
  
  generateRandomNumbers(int amount, int maxNb) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
    final number = Random().nextInt(maxNb) + 1;
    randomNumbers.add(number);
    } 
  }
  generateRandomNumbers(amount,maxNb);
  print(randomNumbers);
}
```

FYI: Variable names are NOT capitalized.

Comment: You´re welcome. If you want to reset the list in the second example just add: randomNumbers = [ ];  before calling the .add list method.

Answer (score 0):

Your random number can be zero because you want a random number between 0 and i, so 0 is in your range , if you want a random number that doesn't include zero in the range you can use a method like this:

```
int nextRangeInt(int min, int max) => min + Random().nextInt((max + 1) - min);
```

in your case :

```
int Num = 1;
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
{
Num = nextRangeInt(1,i);
}
print('Randon num is $Num')
```

Comment: this answer is for use range random, not just this case

Answer (score 0):

You can use like;

```dart
 
var Num;

 for (var i=1; i <= 6; i++) {
    Num = Random().nextInt(i) +1;
    print('Random num is $Num');
 }
```

Comment: It makes no sense to use the loop if you don't use the `Num` value inside of the loop.